# How to make script not crash when wrong username and password is entered? (smtplib - gmail login)

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, smtp, smtp-auth

I have this problem where when the user enters the wrong username and password, it would receive this error and crash (I am fairly new to python):

```
File "/Users/19austinh/Google Drive/Other/Python/Login.py", line 156, in <module>                user.login(euser, epass)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/smtplib.py", line 634, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 vn10sm22434291pbc.21 - gsmtp')
```

Here is my code:

```
while True:
    user = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    user.starttls()
    euser = input("Enter Gmail Username: ")
    epass = input("Enter Gmail Password: ")
    user.login(euser, epass)
    print ("Retrieving Files")
    subjectinput = input("Enter Subject: ")
    msginput = input("Enter Message: ")
    msg = ("\n"+msginput)
    sourcemail = (euser)
    targetmail = input("Enter Your Recipient: ")
    user.sendmail(sourcemail, targetmail, 'Subject: {}\r\n\r\n{}'.format(subjectinput, msg))
    print ("Email Sent")
    ask = input("Whould you like to send another one [Y/N]: ")
    if(ask == "n" or ask == "N" or ask == "no" or ask == "No"):
        break
    if(ask == "y" or ask == "Y" or ask == "yes" or ask == "Yes"):
        continue
```

So how do you make it so when the user enters the wrong username or password, it will go back and ask them for their credentials? Here is what I tried:

```
try:
    user.login(euser, epass)
    except (smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError):
        print ("Invalid Credentials!")
```

However, this only says "Invalid Credentials!" but it lets the program keep running, thus crashing the script. I do not want to use "break" because this will exit out of "while True" and I do not want that to happen. Answers are greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested `while` loop:

```
while True:
    user = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    user.starttls()
    while True:
        euser = input("Enter Gmail Username: ")
        epass = input("Enter Gmail Password: ")
        try:
            user.login(euser, epass)
        except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
            print('Login failure: please reenter credential information.')
            continue
        break
    ...
```

Comment: This is actually what I wanted to try but never got it working. Thanks! Also, is it possible (because I have the extra 2 lines on the bottom that asks you if you want to send another one) to make it so the user does not have to enter their login again if they say "yes"?

Comment: @HelloWorld, Extract lines between `user = stmplib.SMTP .... break` out of the outer `while` loop. :)

Comment: @HelloWorld, Jon Clements posted an answer that you asked; I won't repeat it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after the following construct so that the connection is created, you loop repeatedly until you login successfully, then you do your original send mail or not loop, eg:

```
user = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
user.starttls()
while True: # until we login
    euser = input("Enter Gmail Username: ")
    epass = input("Enter Gmail Password: ")
    try:
        user.login(euser, epass)
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print('Login failure: please reenter credential information.')
        continue
    break
while True:
    pass # Your original stuff using the connection
```